# Möbius function for prime $p$ and gcd of prime $p$ and $d$ where $d$ divides $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, mobius-function

> Let $\mu(p,d)$ denote the value of the Möbius function at the gcd of
> $p$ and $d$. Prove that for every prime $p$ we have
>
> $$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\mu(p,d) = \begin{cases} 1  & \text{if $n=1,$} \\ 2
>  & \text{if $n=p^a,a \ge1,$}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I'm not sure where to start on this question at all; I've always had trouble with these kinds of proofs, and working with primes. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: ...Does the "30 marks" denote that this is an exam or homework problem? I wouldn't feel comfortable helping you with this if that's the case.

Comment: I'll come back tomorrow and write the answer. Too tired right now, it's 4am .

Comment: $n=p^a m$ with $p\nmid m$. If $a \ge 1$ then look at
$$\sum_{d|m}\mu(d)- \sum_{d|m}\mu(pd)$$

Comment: @reuns Wouldn't $\mu(d)=-\mu(pd)$, so you wouldn't have the desired cancellation? Without giving the answer away, I think you'd have to identify a second prime factor $q$ and look at something akin to a symmetric difference with $\{p,q\}$, but in a number theoretic sense.

Comment: @KevinLong $\sum_{d|m}\mu(d)=?$

Comment: But yes you can prove it as you said.

Comment: @reuns Ah, I see. I thought that your answer followed the same idea as mine, but it was something different. Your answer is much more succinct.

Comment: @KevinLong I think yours is fine, because I am implicitly using the two properties of $\mu$: being multiplicative with $\mu(p)=-1,\mu(p^k)=0$ and that it is the Dirichlet inverse of $1$. Whereas you are not using the latter.

Comment: @KevinLong Sorry, for clarification, this is a past paper question that I don't have the solutions for

Comment: @vitamind Please do! All help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1: $n=1$**
In this case our sum simplifies to
$$\mu(1)\mu(p,1)=1$$
The gcd of a prime number and $1$ is obviously $1$.

**Case 2: $n=p^a,a\ge1$**

We have
$$\sum_{d|p^a}\mu(d)\mu(p,d).$$
Here the crutial term is $\mu(d)$. If $d\neq1$ and $d\neq p$, $\mu(d)$ is always equal to zero, since we can rewrite $d$ as $p^2p^b$, where $b\ge0$. If $d=1$ it is trivial to show that the term is equal to $1$. If $d=p$,  $\mu(p)\cdot \mu(p)$ = $1$.

**Case 3: $\mathrm{otherwise}$**

For non-quadratics:
Let $p_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ a prime number.
We start with the product
$p_1\cdot p_2$. The divisors are $1,p_1,p_2$ and $p_1\cdot p_2$. We will define $\nu(p,d) := \mu(d)\mu(p,d)$.
$$\nu(p,1)=+1,\quad \nu(p,p_1)=\mp1, \quad \nu(p,p_2) = -1, \quad \nu(p,p_1p_2)=\pm1$$

If we add another prime, then what happens? The number $p_1p_2p_3$ have the same divisors as $p_1p_2$ but also $p_1p_3$, $p_2p_3$, $p_3$ and $p_1p_2p_3$. So everytime we multiply our expression with another prime we have an increase in $\nu=1$ but the same decrease in $\nu=-1$.

For quadratics: Just an example would be the number $p_1^2p_2$. Divisors, $1,p_1,p_2,p_1p_2,p_1^2,p_1^2p_2$.
Same argument as if it was a non-quadratic but $\nu(p,p_1^2)$ etc. equals zero.

**Remark:**
You can formulate everything more rigorously and better. I had to do it in my head on my phone.